# Bending a plane into a closed surface/cylinder

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm doing a mathematical experiment in Matlab and the result should be a circle in the x,y-plane. But sometimes, the circle starts spiraling. I'm now trying to bend the x,y-plane into a cylinder (as in the following picture). At the moment I only have the x and y coordinates of the points.

I've tried converting them into polar coordinates and then use some 'surf' commando's, but nothing works right now

[image: cylinder]
<sub>(source: [wtcoeselgem.be](http://www.wtcoeselgem.be/andere/plot_cylinder.png))</sub>

**Edit:** I've used the plot3 command, as suggested by Ander Biguri, resulting in the following figure.

[image: cylinder2]
<sub>(source: [wtcoeselgem.be](http://www.wtcoeselgem.be/andere/plot_cylinder3.png))</sub>

Comment: surf will create a sruface, bu tyou want to plot a line right? give those points a Z value and do plot3(x,y,z)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think this will create the same figure as in the picture above. I'm editing my question with a new picture.

Comment: Then you were not clear. The x and y points are from the cylinder? Whats your problem, ploting a cylinder or ploting the points in the cylinder? Because ploting a cylinder is pretty straingthforward: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/cylinder.html

Comment: I'm doing a mathematical experiment and the result should be a circle, but in some cases it spirals out. The output are x and y coordinates in the plane and I want to 'bend' this plane into a cylinder

Comment: Well, then you problem is far beyond "plot points in a cylynder" isnt it?

Comment: Let me try to understand the problem. That"cylinder" is a plane bent into a closed surface?... Wow man, thats a complicated question! a good one though.

Comment: That's a very good understanding :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to do more or less what you want

```
%// Data
xmin = -3;
xmax = 3; %// this piece will get folded into a cylinder
Rc = 5; %// cylinder radius
zmaxc = 5; %// cylinder max z
zminc = -5; %// cylinder min z

%// Spiral
t = linspace(0,1,1000);
r = 1+2*t;
theta = 2*pi*3*t;
x1 = r.*cos(theta);
y1 = r.*sin(theta); %// example spiral. Defined by x1, y1

%// Do the bending
z2 = y1;
phi = (x1-xmin)/(xmax-xmin)*2*pi;
x2 = Rc*cos(phi);
y2 = Rc*sin(phi);

%// Plot cylinder
[xc yc zc] = cylinder(Rc*ones(1,100),100);
zc = zminc + (zmaxc-zminc)*zc;
surf(xc,yc,zc)
shading flat
hold on

%// Plot bent spiral
plot3(x2,y2,z2, 'k.-');
```

Original spiral:

[image]

Two views of the result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 for a better example of curve to fold. the spiral is much more explicit once folded than my poor sine wave (strange choice of colour though :)

Comment: Yes... that's the default color. I didn't bother to change it. +1 too! The curve is irrelevant, I think; the procedure is the same for any curve

Answer (score 4):

I will consider that you have a curve defined by `x` and `y` coordinates which you want to *fold* around a cylinder.

```
%% // Generate sample data
x = linspace(0,10*pi) ;
y2 = cos(x) ;
y1 = 10*cos(x/10) ;
y = y1+y2 ; y = y-min(y) ;
figure, plot(x,y,'-o') ;
```

This produces:
[image: plot flat]

Next I define a basic cylinder, nothing original:

```
%% // Basic cylinder (just for background)
[Xc,Yc,Zc] = cylinder(1,100);
Zc = Zc * max(y) ;
hs = surf(Xc,Yc,Zc) ;
set(hs,'FaceColor',[.8 .8 .8],'FaceAlpha',0.5,'EdgeColor','none') ;
hold on
```

And here comes the interesting bit:

```
%% // Fold the points around the cylinder
Number_of_turn = 2 ;
xrange = [min(x),max(x)] ;
xspan = xrange(2)-xrange(1) ;
xc = x / xspan * 2*pi * Number_of_turn ;

Xp = cos(xc) ;
Zp = y ;
Yp = sin(xc) ;

hp = plot3(Xp,Yp,Zp,'-ok') ;
```

Which render:
[image: plot folded]

For this example I assumed you wanted to wrap your curve around "2 turns" of the cylinder. This is easily changed with the `Number_of_turn` variable.

Note that you can also change the radius of the cylinder by multiplying the `Xp` and `Yp` coordinates by your radius.