# Bending a plane into a conical surface

Tags: matlab

I am currently trying to compute Origami structures on Matlab, and I am looking for a method to bend my crease patterns on a conical surface, in the same way that this answer : [Bending a plane into a closed surface/cylinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26408863/bending-a-plane-into-a-closed-surface-cylinder) into a cylinder.

How can I do this, please ?

Cheers,

Comment: This is not really a specific question and/or is too broad. What have you tried? Show us code for an example of what you're trying to do and where it goes wrong.

Comment: fantastic question, thanks for it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just have to map an (x,y) coordinate into a 3D coordinate for a conical surface. So to do this, it is important to parametrize a conical surface as a function of two variables. Thus:

( r, theta, z ) = ( **a** * z + **c**, theta, z ) for some **a**,**c** you define

Then you just need to create a relationship between (x,y) and (theta,z) so you can find a given (theta,z) as a function of (x,y). Then it comes down to a simple set of for loops to iterate through the (x,y) points to find the mapped coordinates on the conical surface.

**=== Edit ===**

So I wrote some codes to illustrate how simple the mapping can be. First, here are some images. The first is the planar mesh that will be mapped, and the second image is the result.

[image]
[image]

```
% This is file: gen_mesh.m
function [x, y, tri_mesh] = gen_mesh()

% Initialize output coordinates of points that make up the mesh
y = [];
x = [];

% Initialize mesh
tri_mesh= [];

% Number of points in the x dimension
Nx = 5;

% Number of points in the y dimension
Ny = 17;

% For this mesh, make each row have a slightly
% different number of points
x1 = linspace(0,1,Nx);
dx = x1(2)-x1(1);
x2 = linspace(dx/2, 1-dx/2, Nx-1);

% Create the array with the y values
y1 = linspace(0,1,Ny);


%% Generate the associated (x,y) pairs
for iy = 1:Ny
   if( mod(iy,2) == 0 )
       y = [y, ones(1,Nx-1)*y1(iy)];
       x = [x, x2];
   else
       y = [y, ones(1,Nx)*y1(iy)];
       x = [x, x1];
   end
end


%% Generate the Mesh of triangles
% Make sure that the mesh wraps to each 
% opposite x bound. This is to make sure that
% the cyclic nature of the conical surface 
% doesnt mess up the look of the mesh
count = 1;

curr = 1;
ol = [];
el = [];
for iy = 1:Ny

    if( mod(iy, 2) == 0 )
        el.x = x(curr:curr+(Nx-2));
        el.y = y(curr:curr+(Nx-2));
    else

        ol.x = x(curr:curr + Nx - 1);
        ol.y = y(curr:curr + Nx - 1);
    end



    if( iy ~= 1 )
        for i = 2:Nx
            tri_mesh(count).x = [ol.x(i), el.x(i-1), ol.x(i-1)];
            tri_mesh(count).y = [ol.y(i), el.y(i-1), ol.y(i-1)];
            count = count + 1;
        end

        for i = 2:(Nx-1)
            tri_mesh(count).x = [el.x(i), ol.x(i), el.x(i-1)];
            tri_mesh(count).y = [el.y(i), ol.y(i), el.y(i-1)];
            count = count + 1;
        end

        tri_mesh(count).x = [el.x(1), ol.x(1), el.x(end)];
        tri_mesh(count).y = [el.y(1), ol.y(1), el.y(end)];
        count = count + 1;
    end



    if( mod(iy, 2) == 0 )
        curr = curr + (Nx-1);
    else
        curr = curr + Nx;
    end
end

end











% This is file: map_2D_to_3DCone.m
function [xh, yh, z] = map_2D_to_3DCone( x, x_rng, y, y_rng )
% x: an array of x values part of a planar coordinate
%
% x_rng: the smallest and largest possible x values in the planar domain
% ->  x_rng = [min_x, max_x]
%
% y: an array of y values part of a planar coordinate
%
% y_rng: the smallest and largest possible y values in the planar domain
% ->  y_rng = [min_y, max_y]


% The bottom z (height) value
zb = 0;

% The top z value
zt = 1;

% The radius value at z = zb
rb = 3;

% The radius value at z = zt
rt = 1;





%% Obtain the Conical Surface 3D coordinates

% Find z as a function of y in the planar domain
% This mapping is a simple 1-D Lagrange interpolation
z = (zt*( y - y_rng(1) ) - zb*( y - y_rng(2) ))/(diff(y_rng));

% Find the parametrized angle as a function of x
% using a 1D Lagrange interpolation
theta = 2*pi*( x - x_rng(1) )/(diff(x_rng));

% Find the radius as a function of z using
% a simple 1D legrange interpolation
r = ( rt*(z - zb) - rb*(z - zt) )/( zt - zb );



% Find the absolute x and y components of the
% 3D conical coordinates
xh = r.*cos(theta);
yh = r.*sin(theta);


end




% This is in file: PlaneMesh_to_ConicalMesh.m
function mesh3d = PlaneMesh_to_ConicalMesh( mesh2d )
% Generate the 3D version of each planar triangle, based
% on the mapping function that takes an (x,y) planar
% coordinate and maps it onto a conical surface
N = length(mesh2d);
mesh3d(N).x = [];
mesh3d(N).y = [];
mesh3d(N).z = [];


for i = 1:N
    [xh, yh, z] = map_2D_to_3DCone( mesh2d(i).x, [0,1], mesh2d(i).y, [0,1] );
    mesh3d(i).x = xh;
    mesh3d(i).y = yh;
    mesh3d(i).z = z;
end


end





% This is in file: gen3D_MappedCone.m
% Generate the 3D object
close all

% Generate a 2D planar mesh to morph onto
% a conical surface
[x, y, mesh2d] = gen_mesh();

% Map the 2D mesh into a 3D one based on the
% planar to conical surface mapping
mesh3d = PlaneMesh_to_ConicalMesh( mesh2d );

% Obtain the number of triangles making up 
% the mesh
N = length(mesh3d);


% Define a color mapping function for the sake
% of visualizing the mapping
color_map = @(x) [1, 0, 0].*(1-x) + [0, 0, 1].*x;




% Create the first image based on the planar
% mesh

figure(1)
hold on
for i = 1:N
   color = color_map( (i-1)/(N-1) );
   h = fill( mesh2d(i).x,mesh2d(i).y, color );
   set(h, 'facealpha',0.9)
end
axis([0,1,0,1])





% Create the next figure showing the 3D mesh
% based on the planar to conical surface transformation
figure(2)
hold on

for i = 1:N
    color = color_map( (i-1)/(N-1) );
    h = fill3(mesh3d(i).x,mesh3d(i).y,mesh3d(i).z, color);
    set(h, 'facealpha',0.9)
end

grid on
hold off
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid loops to do this ? 
I need my code to be fast because the origami structure I want to 3Dplot in projecting the patterns on a cone can be composed of many points. I already use a loop to ensure the "folding" so it takes a long time.

Comment: The only loop you need to do is a loop over each (x,y) coordinate so you can find its 3-D conical coordinate. That isn't really something you can get out of. I will try to show you an example of this working later. I will post it as an edit to my answer.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I'm sorry I have to leave for the weekend, I will be back to better comment on Tuesday. Does your code also works with this kind of pattern in spiral ? [link](https://www.flickr.com/photos/yoshinobu_miyamoto/15310692332). I managed to code the pattern. Sorry for the strucutre of my code. I begin and it is true that I tend to add lines rather than using functions.

Comment: This code works with any set of (x,y) planar points. To make the complete design you have, you need to form a mesh of triangles, but if you do that right than you will be set!

Comment: Thank you choward for your code, it works very well. I tried it with my patterns made of scalene triangles and isocele triangles. I don't know if you are interested in Origami ? I am looking for a partner to compute help me to compute the end of my GUI... If you have free time, I would be delighted... Let me know. 
http://hpics.li/f2a670e http://hpics.li/e918add

Comment: No problem! Can you upvote/accept my solution? Also, I think that might be an interesting project to help with. Want to give me your email, or facebook or something, and any other info you can as to what you are aiming to do?